# Get Data from Inline with Admin.User Model

Tags: django, django-admin

I am trying to use an 'augmentation' table with the Admin.User Model to store additional data related to that user/login.

Here is my admin.py

```
class UserProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = AppUserProfile
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'profile'


# Define a new User admin
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    inlines = (UserProfileInline,)


# Re-register UserAdmin
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Here is my models.py

```
class AppUserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    usr_tpid = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    usr_cstid = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    db_table = 'app_user_profile'
```

Here is my views.py where I'm trying to get the usr_cstid from the login value.

```
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print(request.POST)
            username = form.cleaned_data['userName']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            userInfo = AppUserProfile.objects.all().filter(user=username)
            print(username)
            print(userInfo)
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                groups = [x.name for x in user.groups.all()]
                full_info = User.objects.all().filter(username=username)
                user_info = User.objects.all().filter(username=username).values('first_name')
                print(full_info)
                request.session['first_name'] = user_info[0]['first_name']
                request.session['user_group'] = groups[0]
                # print(user_info, groups)
                # return render(request, template_name='landingPage.html', context={'user': first_name})
                if 'Administrator' in groups:
                    # return render(request, template_name='adm_landing_page.html', context={'user': first_name})
                    return redirect('AdminPortal:adm_landing_page')
                if 'Supplier' in groups:
                    # return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('adm_landing_page', args=(), kwargs={'user': username}))
                    return render(request, template_name='supplier_landing_page.html', )
                    # return redirect('SupplierPortal:supplier_landing_page')

            else:
                form = LoginForm()
    else:
        form = LoginForm()

    return render(request, 'registration/login.html', {'form': form})
```

However I'm getting the following error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'supplier_ad'
```

It seems this is the line causing the error:

```
    userInfo = AppUserProfile.objects.all().filter(user=username)
```

I am not sure what I have wrong, or how to link back to those values.

Comment: what is supplier_ad, you did not post https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: supplier_ad is the username that is logging into the website.  I will review and see about updating my question. Thanks.

Comment: @iklinac I'm hoping I got what you needed in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what are you trying to achieve with this but you cannot filter `user object` by `username` **string**  rather by `user object` or users `id` or you could do something like this

```
userInfo = AppUserProfile.objects.all().filter(user__username=username)
```

If you are expecting one  `AppUserProfile` instance use `get()` instead of `filter()`

Also I am not seeing what exactly you are trying to achieve as when you login your user it is always accessible with `request.user` and depending on relation you could get resulting profile for instance assuming `OneToOne` relationship `request.user.profile`

Comment: I am trying to access the values in the related `AppUserProfile` model for that user/login.  I need the `usr_cstid` value to filter the data accessible by certain users.  Thanks for your answer, giving it a shot now.

Comment: Thanks, this got me to exactly what I needed.